# C++ - How to restrict access to global variable while allowing access from within interrupt service routine and template class specialization

Tags: c++, global-variables, interrupt, encapsulation

I'm currently working with the ATmega328p (found in Arduino Uno) and abstracting the interrupt vector table to be modifiable at runtime.

My problem is the accessibility and visibility of the global variable `g_VectorTable`.
I want it to be only accessible from the implementation, but not from anything else.
Is there a way to work around this by defining the variable as **static** with some other modifications?
(The implementation by specialization needs to stay, can be moved around to `.tcc` files, restructured etc.)

I'm aware that a global variable is not the solution. I'm looking for a construct that allows me to access that array from within the interrupt service routine as well as from the template specialization while restricting access for everything else.

The current state of my project is:

interface `<hal/InterruptVectorTable.hpp>`:

```cpp
template <class Impl, class IRQType>
class InterruptVectorTable
{
  private:
    InterruptVectorTable();
  public:
    InterruptVectorTable(InterruptVectorTable const&) = delete;
    void operator=(InterruptVectorTable const&) = delete;
    static auto getInstance() -> InterruptVectorTable&;
    auto setISR(IRQType InterruptIndex, void (*Callback)(void)) -> void;
};
```

Implementation by specialization `InterruptVectorTable.hpp`:

```cpp
extern void (*g_VectorTable[26])(void);
template <>
class InterruptVectorTable<DeviceAtMega328p, IRQType> // IRQType is an enum class
{
  private:
    InterruptVectorTable()
    {
        auto DefaultHandler = []() -> void {};

        g_VectorTable[0] = 0x0;

        for (uint8_t i = 1; i < 26; i++)
        {
            g_VectorTable[i] = DefaultHandler;
        }
        m_VectorTable = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(g_VectorTable);
    }
    uint8_t* m_VectorTable;

   public:

    static auto getInstance() -> InterruptVectorTable&
    {   
        static InterruptVectorTable instance;
        return instance;
    }

    auto setISR(IRQType InterruptIndex, void (*Callback)(void)) -> void
    {
        g_VectorTable[static_cast<uint8_t>(InterruptIndex)] = Callback;
    }
    // ...
};
```

Implementation `InterruptVectorTable.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

void (*g_VectorTable[26])(void) = {0x0, };

ISR(INT0_vect)
{
    g_VectorTable[1]();
}
ISR(INT1_vect)
{
    g_VectorTable[2]();
}
ISR(PCINT0_vect)
{
    g_VectorTable[3]();
}
ISR(PCINT1_vect)
{
    g_VectorTable[4]();
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are able to modify such global variable, there is now way of restricting the scope of a global variable in C++.

Comment: I am able to change the global variable. It is possible to use a static variable, but it needs to work with the template specialization and the interrupt service routines.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem is:

split the specialization into two parts:
- part one: the definition of the specialization in the header file.
- part two: the implementation of the specialization in the cpp file

Part one(`InterruptVectorTable.hpp`):

```cpp
template <>
class InterruptVectorTable<DeviceAtmega328p, IRQType>
{
  private:
    InterruptVectorTable();
  public:
    InterruptVectorTable(InterruptVectorTable const&) = delete;
    void operator=(InterruptVectorTable const&) = delete;
    static auto getInstance() -> InterruptVectorTable&;
    auto setISR(IRQType InterruptIndex, void (*Callback)(void)) -> void;
};
```

Part two(`InterruptVectorTable.cpp`):

```cpp
#inlcude "InterruptVectorTable.hpp"

static void (*s_VectorTable[26])(void);

ISR(INT0_vect)
{
    g_VectorTable[1]();
}
// ...

auto InterruptVectorTable<DeviceAtmega328p, IRQType>::setISR(IRQType InterruptIndex, void (*Callback)(void)) -> void {
    s_VectorTable[static_cast<int>(IRQType)] = Callback;
}
//...
```

The last step is to put the variable definition into the .cpp source file (see above) and mark it as `static` to hide it from external access, while being in the global visibility scope.